# Flutter Rows and columns

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a flutter beginner. How to create elements like 4*2 tabular columns without borders? I tried, But I didn't get the alignment I wanted. [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1a3f.jpg)   
 can someone guide me on how I can solve this problem? Here is my simplified code for the build method of my stateful widget:

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 0.9,
                            color: Color(0xff908f8f),
                          ),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 295.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                              child: Table(
                                children: const [
                                  TableRow(children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "1",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Mohit",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Pre",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "25",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                  TableRow(children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "2",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Ankit",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Pre",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "27",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this layout is to make a row widget containing 4 columns with Text(name) and Text(value) as children.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('name'),
        Text('value'),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('name'),
        Text('value'),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('name'),
        Text('value'),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('name'),
        Text('value'),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

And then you can style each Column with Container with BoxDecoration.
Wrap Text widgets with Padding or place SizedBox between them with height of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code I have try it Two ways use your choice

#### Using Widgets:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Total',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          'BHD19.900',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Tax',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          'BHD1.990',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Quantity',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          '1',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Status',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          'Paid',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

#### Create widgets/function and Call

```
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    myWidget('Total', 'BHD19.900'),
    myWidget('Tax', 'BHD1.990'),
    myWidget('Quantity', '1'),
    myWidget('Status', 'Paid'),
  ],
),
```

Your Widget:

```
myWidget(String title, String subTitle) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          subTitle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This might be the best way to achieve the layout like what you want.

````
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 0.9,
                            color: Color(0xff908f8f),
                          ),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 295.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text('title'),
                                      Text('sub-title'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text('title'),
                                      Text('sub-title'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text('title'),
                                      Text('sub-title'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text('title'),
                                      Text('sub-title'),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),```

And you can style each column inside container with BoxDecoration.
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a 4x2 table, but the current code involves a container with borders. If you want to create a table without borders and achieve a specific alignment, you might want to consider using a `DataTable` widget in Flutter. Here's a simplified example:

```dart
DataTable(
  columnSpacing: 10.0, // Adjust the spacing between columns
  columns: [
    DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Status')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Age')),
  ],
  rows: [
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text('1')),
      DataCell(Text('Mohit')),
      DataCell(Text('Pre')),
      DataCell(Text('25')),
    ]),
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text('2')),
      DataCell(Text('Ankit')),
      DataCell(Text('Pre')),
      DataCell(Text('27')),
    ]),
    // Add more DataRow entries as needed
  ],
)
```

Adjust the `columnSpacing` property and the contents of the `DataRow` widgets to fit your desired layout. This should give you a clean and aligned table without the need for additional containers and borders.

Feel free to modify this example to suit your specific needs!